# Transfer localhost:8081 to my Webserver via FTP

Tags: ftp, webserver, file-transfer, motion

I have a raspberry pi with `motion` installed. I have a `mjpg` at `localhost:8081` and want to transfer it to an other webserver on the internet, so it's kind of a relay. I don't know where to find the `mjpg` on the file system for easy transfer, it's not in the configured folder. So, what's the best way to transfer my `localhost:8081` to my webserver? It shows the live image of my webcam.

Comment: Your `localhost:8081` is probably `motion`'s stream port: although `motion` presents it to the web browser as a mjpg file, it's actually relaying live data directly from the camera to the browser. So, do you want to make a snapshot or recording from the camera and transfer that to the webserver, or do you want the webserver to be able to access the webcam and see the live image?

Comment: i want to relay the mjpg to my other server on the internet

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be accomplished using ssh. Take a look at forwarding connections over ssh.

```
ssh -R remote_socket:host:hostport
```

If, for example, your webserver is `example.com`:

```
ssh -R 8081:localhost:8081 example.com
```

When run on your raspberry pi, will forward all connections pointed to port 8081 on your webserver over ssh to your raspberry pi.

I recommend trying this using another host on your LAN first to see if it meets your needs. From the raspberry pi:

```
ssh -R 8081:localhost:8081 other_lan_host
```

Alternatively, you can use the `-L` option and run the command from the LAN host that you are testing with:

```
ssh -L 8081:raspberrypihost:8081
```